# PHP - check if a string has 2 words, and if true append a html tag to the 2nd one

Tags: php, html, string

Whats the **fastest** possible way to do this?

I think the code below works, but I'm sure there's a faster way to achieve what I want:

```
$words = explode(" ", $string);
if(!empty($words[1]) $words[1] = '<span>'.$words[1].'</span>';
$string = implode(" ", $words);
```

What do you think?

Comment: What is the reason of looking for **fastest** solution in such trivia task? Implement the most readable one.

Comment: well the code would be run quite a few times on a page. something similar to a source formatting script :)

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Is this snippet the bottleneck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As zerkms and deceze point out in their comments, I'm sure your scripts will receive more effective optimizations elsewhere unless you're sure your performance bottleneck lies in the above snippet.

That said, if for example you don't want to muck around with arrays, try this, assuming each word is only separated by one space character:

```
$string = trim($string);

if (strpos($string, ' ') !== false) {
    $string = str_replace(' ', ' <span>', $string) . '</span>';
}
```